# Special characters on query_string in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

Assuming I have an Index & I added to it a document, by this statement:

```
POST /temp/item
{
    "text": "dave@domain.com dave@do-main.com one,two three:four"
}
```

I would like some query statements to return this document, for example:

1. `*@domain*`
2. `*@do-*`
3. `one,two`
4. `three:four` --> This actually yield an error

Each selected by a statement similar to this:

```
GET /temp/item/_search
{
 "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*@domain*",
            "allow_leading_wildcard": "true",
            "default_operator": "AND"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

None of them returned.

I understood the reason was that the Analyzer set to `standard`, it splitted the text by any wordboundry. So I figured that I must change the analyzer to `whitespace`, like this:

```
PUT /temp
{
  "mappings": {
    "item" : {
      "properties" : {
        "text" : {
          "type" :    "string",
          "analyzer": "whitespace"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Doing so didn't solve the problem. None of the statement returned the document.

## Questions

1. How can I configure the Index or Change the query statement so that all of the examples above will capture.
2. Why after I changed the analyzer to "whitespace" Elasticsearch didn't return the document?

Answer (score 4):

Almost there  you need to explicitly specify the 'field' for  [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) to match against.
One can specify using the `default_field` or `fields` option the case

Example:

```
{
 "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*@domain*",
            "fields": [
               "text"
            ], 
            "allow_leading_wildcard": "true",
            "default_operator": "AND"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If nothing is specified `query_string` would use the `_all` field.

2) `three:four` needs to be wrapped in double-quotes else it would be interpreted as `field:three` match `query:four`
Example:

```
{
 "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "\"three:four\"",
            "fields": [
               "text"
            ], 
            "allow_leading_wildcard": "true",
            "default_operator": "AND"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```